# Including models inside Inline Models in Django

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to add models inside inline models in Django?

I have 3 models as below

```
class Platform(models.Model):
    platformId = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Partner(models.Model):
    platform = models.ForeignKey(Platform,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

class Inventory(models.Model):
    partner = models.ForeignKey(Partner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    display = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

In admin, I added Partner as inline in Platform as below

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Platform, Partner, Inventory

class PartnerInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Partner
    extra = 1

class InventoryInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Inventory
    extra = 1

class PlatformAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    inlines = [
        PartnerInline
    ]
```

Now what I want is to add the InventoryInline as part of the partner. Is it Possible?
That means when I add a partner I want to add inventory for each partner.
Inline inside and inline. Is this possible?
Or is there any other way to achieve this?

I am new to Django

Comment: Maybe [django-nested-admin](https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin/) can help you there.

Comment: @wfehr Thanks, buddy. This is exactly what I was looking for. Served the purpose.